# How to set multiple Internet Explorer X-UA-Compatible

Tags: internet-explorer, x-ua-compatible

I have a Default.aspx web page. In this page some element required:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

Another elements required:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

I want both this two elements, how we can set this?

If I set :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge; IE=8"/>
```

I want same error, first element work correctly, but second elements not work.

Answer (score 1):

While you can specify multiple document mode values for a page, these specify fallback conditions for when the preferred (initial) document mode isn't available.

You cannot selectively use edge mode for part of the page and revert to quirks mode for another part of the page.  (Well, you could in IE8, but this was removed in IE9.)

Your best bet is to separate quirks mode content to a separate page linked from a page containing standards mode markup.  Do be aware that many legacy features are no longer supported in [recent versions of IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467852(v=vs.85).aspx) (or at all in Edge).